# Java Spring 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, config, http-status-code-401

I'm following a tutorial on Java Spring, and found an authentication code with jwt. So far there is no problem, I can generate tokens and login/register and use these tokens on routes for post/get request. But the problem is, after 2 minutes I'm getting an 401 unauthorized error. And I could not solve it.

The code from the tutorial I'm following:

JwtAuthEntryPoint.java

```
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
 
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthEntryPoint.class);
    
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException e) 
                             throws IOException, ServletException {
      
        logger.error("Unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error -> Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
 
    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider tokenProvider;
 
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
 
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthTokenFilter.class);
 
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
                    HttpServletResponse response, 
                    FilterChain filterChain) 
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
          
            String jwt = getJwt(request);
            if (jwt!=null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
 
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication 
                    = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
 
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e);
        }
 
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
 
    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
          
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
          return authHeader.replace("Bearer ","");
        }
 
        return null;
    }
}
```

JwtProvider.java

```
public class JwtProvider {
 
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);
 
    @Value("${grokonez.app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;
 
    @Value("${grokonez.app.jwtExpiration}")
    private int jwtExpiration;
 
    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {
 
        UserPrinciple userPrincipal = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
 
        return Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpiration))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                    .compact();
    }
 
    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                      .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                      .parseClaimsJws(token)
                      .getBody().getSubject();
    }
 
    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature -> Message: {} ", e);
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty -> Message: {}", e);
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
 
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
 
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
 
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
 
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything depends on the value you have set for `setExpiration` in `jws.bulder`.

in your example you need to change `jwtExpiration` which is read from the configuration file.

another way to do that could be replacing some code like:

```
.setExpiration(Date.from(Instant.now() + "your_desired_time"))
```

in `JwtProvider.java` file instead of your code.

***note that the value you set, is the expiration time in *milliseconds***.

Comment: In application.properties I have this : grokonez.app.jwtSecret=jwtExampleSecretKey
grokonez.app.jwtExpiration=86400

Comment: so **86400** is your expiration time in ***milliseconds***. simply change it to every number you need.